# How are parallel lines defined in n-dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

WolframMathWorld on [parallel lines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelLines.html):

> Two lines in two-dimensional Euclidean space are said to be parallel
> if they do not intersect.
>
> In three-dimensional Euclidean space, parallel lines not only fail to
> intersect, but also maintain a constant separation between points
> closest to each other on the two lines. Therefore, parallel lines in
> three-space lie in a single plane (Kern and Blank 1948, p. 9). Lines
> in three-space which are not parallel but do not intersect are called
> skew lines.

How are parallel lines commonly, or reasonably, defined for dimensions higher than three?

Comment: The argument of co-planarity still holds in n-space.

Answer (score 2):

A good definition is:

> Two straight lines are parallel if  there is a plane that contains the two lines and the two lines have no common points.

This definition make sense also in $n-$dimensional spaces, with a suitable definition of what a plane is, as  for an [affine plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane) (because parallelism is an affine notion).

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_1,P_2$ be distinct points on a line $l_1$ and $Q_1,Q_2$ be distinct points on a line $l_2$.

Then, $l_1$ and $l_2$ are parallel if and only if $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2} = k \cdot \overrightarrow{Q_1Q_2}$ for some $k \in \mathbb R$.